# Check which ids in id list already exist in NDB (python)

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, app-engine-ndb

I have a list of entities I'm loading into my front-end. If I don't these entities yet in my NDB, I load them from another data source. If I do have them in my NDB, I obviously load them from there.

Instead of querying for every key separately to test whether it exists, I'd like to query for the whole list (for efficiency reasons) and find out what IDs exist in the NDB and what don't.

It could return a list of booleans, but any other practical solution is welcome.

Thanks already for your help!

Answer (score 0):

How about doing a `ndb.get_multi()` with your list, and then comparing the results with your original list to find what you need to retrieve from the other data source? Something like this perhaps...

```
list_of_ids = [1,2,3 ... ]

# You have to use the keys to query using get_multi() (this is assuming that
# your list of ids are also the key ids in NDB)
keys_list = [ndb.key('DB_Kind', x) for x in list_of_ids]
results = ndb.get_multi(keys_list)
results = [x for x in results if x is not None] # Get rid of any Nones
result_keys = [x.key.id() for x in results]
diff = list(set(list_of_ids) - set(result_keys)) # Get the difference in the lists
# Diff should now have a list of ids that weren't in NDB, and results should have
# a list of the entities that were in NDB.
```

I can't vouch for the performance of this, but it should be more efficient then querying for each entity one at a time. In my experience using `ndb.get_multi()` is a huge performance booster, since it cuts down on a huge amount of RPCs. You could likely tweak the code that I posted above, but perhaps it will at least point you in the right direction.